# Two networking interfaces trying to get an IP via DHCP

Tags: networking, ethernet, systemd

When using:

## /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "<myssid>"
wpa-psk "<mypasswd>"
```

why is the boot blocked for more than 1 minute if no ethernet cable is connected?

Why doesn't it go to the next lines and use wlan0 instead ?

I would like that **if no ethernet cable is connected**, the system doesn't wait so long, and try with wlan0 instead. How to do that?

I'm using Debian Jessie with `networking.service`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change `auto eth0` to `allow-hotplug eth0` in your `/etc/network/interfaces`. This would keep your system away from trying to get address by DHCP when interface isn't connected. This should fix the problem.

Also, you can set lower timeout to DHCP client. You may set `timeout 3;` in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.
It will set 3 seconds timeout for getting IP over DHCP.
Longer time should make process more reliable on slower networks, but takes more time. Shorter time could left you without an address when network is on load.

Comment: Thanks! In some docs, I see that we have to use `auto <interface>` AND `allow-hotplug <interface>` together. In some other places, I see allow-hotplug should replace auto. What do you think?

Comment: It seems that `allow-hotplug` alone is enough, and replaces `auto`